# BottomNavigationView layout broken, when add menu items programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, androidx, bottomnavigationview

For some reason BottomNavigationView has a visual bug in layout. Does anyone know any way to fix it? The problem resolves after any button is clicked or after I minimize app and restore it.

#### This is how it is supposed to look:

Everything works when menu is inflated via XML.

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        ...
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_4_game" />
```

[image: Correct]

#### When I added MenuItem programmatically:

```
navigationView.menu.clear()
navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.bottom_navigation4)
```

[image: Incorrect]

#### We may see in LayoutInspector, that there are actually 5 items, but two of them are overlayed and not seen:

[image: LayoutInspector]

The problem is probably in `BottomNavigationMenuView`. In LayoutInspector `getWidth()` returns 0. Invalidating views didn't help.
[image: width is 0]

Comment: Tried clearing the menu first then adding all items again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a weird code block in the app, that was to blame. Turns out, that TransitionManager didn't end its transitions with ConstraintLayout. This code: `updateConstraints {}` was called immediately after dynamically changing BottomNavigationView, hence its child views transition was interrupted, I guess.

```
private fun updateConstraints(f: ConstraintSet.() -> Unit) {
    TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(root)
    val set = ConstraintSet().apply { clone(root) }
    set.f()
    set.applyTo(root)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create dynamic BottomNavigationView with 2 different menu items set,

So instead of dynamically adding the menu item, use 2 different xml layouts (which have define 2 different app:menu property) and based on the conditions switch between them in your code then.

So, XML would look like this:

```
<BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
                app:elevation="8dp"
                app:itemIconTint="?attr/nav_item_color_state_red"
                app:itemTextColor="?attr/nav_item_color_state_red"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_1" />


            <BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation_mini_player"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_bar_height"
                app:elevation="8dp"
                app:itemIconTint="?attr/nav_item_color_state_red"
                app:itemTextColor="?attr/nav_item_color_state_red"
                app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_2" />
```

Comment: This is not optimal solution, considering that I have 5 different configuration variants of BottomNavigationView. I need to inflate menu dynamically.